# Show post of users followed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the `act_as_follower` gem. Where:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  acts_as_followable
  # ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_follower
  has_one :section
  has_many :posts
  # ...
end
```

SectionController:

```
def follow
  @section = Section.find(params[:id])
  @section.user = current_user

  if @section.user == nil
    # We don't follow this yet
    @section.user.follow(@section)
    msg = "You are suscribed to this Section"
  elsif @section.user.following?(@section)
    # We already follow this
    @section.user.stop_following(@section)
    msg = "You are't suscribed to this Section anymore"
  else
    # We don't follow this yet
    @section.user.follow(@section)
    msg = "You are suscribed to this Section"
  end
  redirect_to section_path(@section), :notice => msg
end
```

All this is working fine but I want to show the articles of the sections followed in order `created_at desc` at the `articles.index`.

Comment: It seems wrong that accessing `/follow` might *un*-follow.

Comment: Yea I didn't see that, I will change it, thanks!.

Comment: `if @section.user == nil` is almost always better expressed as `if !@section.user`. It avoids mistakes like `if @section_user = nil` and makes it more readable. What's odd is you test that it is `nil` and then go and call methods on it?!